# How to use enum properties in OpenApi 3.0.1

Tags: java, openapi, enumeration

I have an enum like this:

```
@Getter
public enum ErrorCode implements BaseError {
    // @formatter:off
    FOO(100001, "Foo message.",
    BAR(100002, "Bar message."), 
.
.
.

    FOOBAR(300003, "FOOBAR message.");

    public final int errorId;
    public final String errorMsg;

    ErrorCode(int errorId, String errorMsg) {
        this.errorId = errorId;
        this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    }
}
```

I know, I can use `@Schema(implementation = ErrorCode.class)` to display the enum in SqggerUI but it displays the name. Ist there a way to display the error code (or any other defined properties of an enum)?

In this case I would like to display the list of *errorCodes* instead of the default which  displays the list of the enum *names*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, OpenApi uses enum's `toString()`, which is by default implemented as calling `name()`. If you override the enum's `toString()`. you will reach your goal.

I can't see any reason why you should not redefine `toString()` for a Java enum, I am not aware of any contract which this should go against.

Comment: It could be that I have a more general/important usage of the toString() method. Hence, it would be better to override the toString() method related to the major use. It would be great that the @Schema annotation would have an appropriate additional property for this.

Comment: I am curious: what else do you need `toString()` for?